# New variable based on first appearance of another variable in each group in R

Tags: r, datatable, data-manipulation

I have a long data frame like this one:

```
set.seed(17)
players<-rep(1:2, c(5,5))
decs<-sample(1:3,10,replace=TRUE)
world<-sample(1:2,10,replace=TRUE)
gamematrix<-cbind(players,decs,world)
gamematrix<-data.frame(gamematrix)
gamematrix

     players decs world
1        1    1     1
2        1    3     1
3        1    2     2
4        1    3     2
5        1    2     2
6        2    2     2
7        2    1     2
8        2    1     1
9        2    3     2
10       2    1     2
```

I want to create for *each* player a new variable, that is based on the **first** appearance of the decs==3 variable, and the state of the world.

That is, if when the first appearance of "decs", the state of the world was "1", then the new variable should get the value of "6", otherwise, "7", as follows:

```
    players decs world player_type
1        1    1     1           6
2        1    3     1           6
3        1    2     2           6
4        1    3     2           6
5        1    2     2           6
6        2    2     2           7
7        2    1     2           7
8        2    1     1           7
9        2    3     2           7
10       2    1     2           7
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your expected output; `player_type` seems to be simply `players + 5`, irrespective of any *"first appearance of "decs""*, is it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `tidyverse` approach might be a little cumbersome but it should give you what you want.

```
library(tidyverse)
left_join(
  gamematrix,
  gamematrix %>%
    filter(decs == 3) %>%
    group_by(players) %>%
    slice(1) %>%
    mutate(player_type = ifelse(world == 1, 6, 7)) %>%
    select(players, player_type),
  by = 'players'
)
#   players decs world player_type
#1        1    1     1           6
#2        1    3     1           6
#3        1    2     2           6
#4        1    3     2           6
#5        1    2     2           6
#6        2    2     2           7
#7        2    1     2           7
#8        2    1     1           7
#9        2    3     2           7
#10       2    1     2           7
```

The idea is to `filter` you data for observations where `decs == 3`, extract the first element per 'players', add `player_type` subject to the state of the 'world' and finally merge with your original data.

Comment: @YefR Glad it worked. Consider to accept any of the answer if they solved your problem. Regards

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `cumsum(decs==3) == 1` to find first occurrence of `decs == 3` for a player. Now, `dplyr::case_when` can be used to assign player type.

```
library(dplyr)

gamematrix %>% group_by(players) %>%
mutate(player_type = case_when(
   world[first(which(cumsum(decs==3)==1))] == 1 ~ 6L,
   world[first(which(cumsum(decs==3)==1))] == 2 ~ 7L,
  TRUE                              ~ NA_integer_))


# # A tibble: 10 x 4
# # Groups: players [2]
#   players  decs world player_type
#     <int> <int> <int>       <int>
# 1       1     1     1           6
# 2       1     3     1           6
# 3       1     2     2           6
# 4       1     3     2           6
# 5       1     2     2           6
# 6       2     2     2           7
# 7       2     1     2           7
# 8       2     1     1           7
# 9       2     3     2           7
# 10       2     1     2           7
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(gamematrix)[, player_type := c(7, 6)[any(decs == 3& world == 1) + 1],
              by =  players]
gamematrix
#    players decs world player_type
# 1:       1    1     1           6
# 2:       1    3     1           6
# 3:       1    2     2           6
# 4:       1    3     2           6
# 5:       1    2     2           6
# 6:       2    2     2           7
# 7:       2    1     2           7
# 8:       2    1     1           7
# 9:       2    3     2           7
#10:       2    1     2           7
```